# std::set::insert: duplicates using a user-defined class

Tags: c++, insert, set, duplicates

I am using C++ set container to remove duplicates, but am having a problem with a user-defined class. I defined the comparison operator as below and it works well:

```
bool operator < (const TLineSegment& other) const
{
    int cx1 = (int)((x1 + x2) / 2.0);
    int cy1 = (int)((y1 + y2) / 2.0);
    int cx2 = (int)((other.x1 + other.x2) / 2.0);
    int cy2 = (int)((other.y1 + other.y2) / 2.0);

    if (cx1 == cx2)
        return (cy1 < cy2);
    else
        return (cx1 < cx2);
}
```

However, the below code by adding more condition (no duplicate within a certain range) contains a very few duplicates. I found it working in most cases, but it sometimes doesn't work, really weird. One case I found was two TLineSegments are the same (but not the same instance) and both of them were inserted.

```
bool operator < (const TLineSegment& other) const
{
    const int epi = 5;
    int cx1 = (int)((x1 + x2) / 2.0);
    int cy1 = (int)((y1 + y2) / 2.0);
    int cx2 = (int)((other.x1 + other.x2) / 2.0);
    int cy2 = (int)((other.y1 + other.y2) / 2.0);

    if (abs(cx1 - cx2) < epi) {
        if (abs(cy1 - cy2) < epi) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return (cy1 < cy2);
        }
    }
    else {
        return (cx1 < cx2);
    }
```

Comment: What about equal results? You don't seem to handle that case.

Comment: Your logic is flawed (All lines on the x-axis, where x1 = -n and x2 = +n, are the same for any n)

Comment: Are you intentionally comparing only centers or line segments? Both comparators will say that two different line segments with the same center are equal.

Comment: The std::set duplicates objects because it assumes that < is transitive. i.e: if a < b and b < c then a < c.
But your second comparator allows situations where a < b is true, b < c is true and a < c is false eg:
a's center is (3, -5) b's center is (0, 0) c's center is (5, -5)

Answer (score 0):

Let's compare the line segment `(-n,0):(n,0)` to the line segment `(-x,-y):(x,y)`. So `(cx1,cy1)` and `(cx2,cy2)` are both `(0,0)`. For both implementations of `operator<`, the result will be `false` in either direction, which implies that the two line segments are equivalent. That is, any line segment centered at `(0,0)` is equivalent to every other such line segment?!

This is obviously incorrect.

The simplest thing is to take advantage of [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) having `operator<` defined and do:

```
std::tuple<int, int, int, int> tied() const {
    // can be just auto in C++14. typically I'd say use std::tie()
    // but we're dealing with ints right?
    return std::make_tuple(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

bool operator < (const TLineSegment& other) const
{
    return tied() < other.tied();
}
```